# Watir select option not in list

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver, selectlist

I'm using watir to test/run through my site.

I'm wondering if it is possible to use watir to set the value of a select list that is not on the options list. I've noticed that with Ruby Mechanize you can simply set the value of the field, but it is not quite the same with Watir.

Additional details (extracted from comments):

There is a select for the page size (i.e. how many items to show per page) named pageSize. The options are 5, 10, 20, and 30. However, for testing purposes I'd like to display more than that (e.g. 100). I'm using browser.select_list(:name, "pageSize").select "30" to select the 30. But browser.select_list(:name, "pageSize").select "100" wouldn't work since there is not option with the value 100.

How might I get the page to return 100 values per page?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add an example of what you had in mind?

Comment: Sure! There is a select for the page size (i.e. how many items to show per page) named pageSize. The options are 5, 10, 20, and 30. However, for testing purposes I'd like to display more than that (e.g. 100).

I'm using `browser.select_list(:name, "pageSize").select "30"` to select the 30. But `browser.select_list(:name, "pageSize").select "100"` wouldn't work since there is not option with the value 100.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Watir should return a `Watir::Exception::NoValueFoundException` if the value does not exist as an option. https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/blob/master/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/select.rb#L57

Comment: Unless it is a custom control that lets you input your own values, then no you cannot do this.  although depending on how it is controlled there still might be other methods to spoof the system into giving you larger number of results per page.

Comment: Note: if the page allowed you to set the select list for a value not present, and accepted that, you ought to be filing bugs regarding security..  Forms of any type that allow you to provide a value in a select list that is not there to start with are generally a bad idea, big 'spoofing' security risk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Watir is designed to do the things that a user can do on a page for testing purposes. That being said, many of those select list size dropdowns are updating the url, often resulting in a page like: http://example.com/sprockets?per_page=10

If that is the case, then you might be able to scrape and then change the value in the url to see what you want.

Comment: I see, that's useful thanks.
Do you know if there is a way to simply append that to the end of the url?

Comment: Well, you need to figure out the String of the url you actually want and navigate to it like you normally would with ```browser.goto``` You can hard code it, or get the current ```browser.url```and add on whatever the value you need for ```?per_page=100```, etc.

Comment: in short, look at the existing url for the page after you have set the page size..  If you see the page size as a query string parameter, then you can perhaps spoof a non supported value.  If it is not a parameter than the value is saved somewhere else.  So look at cookies, and HTTP request header values, might be saved in one of those places.. if not is likely server side and not much you can do